# Capybara: cannot find CSS and page.body is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I've just started writing **integration tests** with **Capybara** and I am running into the following symptoms after successfully accessing a page.

- `@response.body` shows the correct HTML as expected.
- `page.body` shows nothing.
- `save_and_open_page` saves the file but the file is empty.
- `click_on("#item")` fails (note I can see it in `@response.body`). Many other types of CSS access also fail here.

I surmise that Capybara failing to access known CSS is related to its rendering a blank page. Is there an underlying reason for all this behavior?

Comment: what `@response.body` are you referring to? Capybara doesn't provide or access @response - it sounds like you are mixing up controller and integration/feature tests

Comment: @TomWalpole That's quite possible - I'm doing an integration test, navigating through pages, and checking their content is what I expect. Because `page.body` is blank, I've found success with `@response.body`.

Comment: Since capybara doesn't use `@response` at all, it would seem you're not using the capybara #visit method to actually load the first page - from which you can then navigate using the other Capybara methods.  You should never be accessing `@response` in a test using capybara.  Maybe you should provide one of your tests so we can see what you're doing

Comment: @TomWalpole #visit was the issue - I didn't know I needed that. So, just to clarify: a functional test could/should test the output of a controller method using `@response.body`, whereas an integration test can test the actual rendered page using `page.body`. Is this correct? It seems there's some overlap there...

Comment: Capybara is designed to emulate a user using a browser, you visit pages, click links, etc. and then assert against what is shown on the page -  that is usually done using the matchers built-in to capybara -- have_text/assert_text/have_field/etc -- on the page or scoped elements found on the page.  When using Capybara you use visit to load pages - it has no support for direct - get/post/put/etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `#visit` to have Capybara go to a page.  Capybara is designed to emulate a user using a browser - it has no support for direct get/post/put... since a user doesn't have that.  It also has no direct access to the response from the app, since the browser handles that.  What it does let you do is move around the app, in a browser, like the user would and then assert against elements of the page appearing, disappearing, and displaying expected information